# Visual Studio MFC Toolbar Editor icon order won't update

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I've been trying to create a custom toolbar in a MFC project in Visual Studio 2010.  I've been following the Sketcher tutorial in Ivan Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2010.  The problem I'm running into is that the toolbar doesn't update to reflect the order and spacing of icons I have created.

I've created a small screenshot to demonstrate the problem:
[image: MFC toolbar editor example]

In the background is the visual studio toolbar editor with my desired toolbar configuration.  In the foreground is the actual app, which does not reflect the spacing or order of icons I've designed.  It does reflect NEW icons being added, and the icons work fine, but I just can't seem to get them to re-order or appropriately space themselves.  They just append to the end in whatever order I create them.

I've tried the rudimentary techniques of restarting both VS and windows, but to no avail.

Any tips on getting it to play nicely?  Lacking that, is there somewhere to manually view or edit the code generated by the toolbar editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, if you create an MFC SDI/MDI project in VS.NET 2005, there is no such issue. It happens in VS.NET 2008 and 2010.

In fact, your rearrangement of the standard toolbar **does** takes effect. It's just not showing you the default state. To restore the state: click the small arrow button at the end of toolbar -> Add or Remove Buttons -> Standard -> Reset Toolbar.

Though I'm not 100% sure why it happens like this(design like this or a bug), there is a way to work around it and it works:

Add following code to the end of `CMainFrame::LoadFrame(...)`

```
BOOL CMainFrame::LoadFrame(UINT nIDResource, DWORD dwDefaultStyle, CWnd* pParentWnd, CCreateContext* pContext) 
{
...

// Explicitly restore toolbar state
m_wndToolBar.RestoreOriginalstate();

return TRUE;
}
```

**I recommend you to contact Microsoft support engineers as there's little resource on the web.**

Comment: Thanks, Eric.  That explains it very well.

Comment: The "Reset Toolbar" to click is in the application's toolbar's drop-down NOT visual studio to disambiguate.

Comment: I found this after I found out I had a toolbar issue after I was scratching my head about why my toolbar wasn't updating after moving icons around. Deleting registry workspace keys fixed it...but to implement this code verbatim `m_wndToolBar.RestoreOriginalstate();` will fail with member not found. I figured out that the syntax is wrong via the autosense.... Using VS2017, I had to replace it as `m_wndToolBar.RestoreOriginalState();` where the difference is it is missing the `Capitol S` on the word `state`. Hopefully this helps someone if they don't know any better.

Answer (score 3):

The reason could be that the toolbar state is already loaded from the registry whenever your application starts. So the framework reads the toolbar state and adds the new buttons to the end. Is there a Workspace key in your Registry and did you try to delete it anytime you make changes to the toolbar? The key should be at a location like HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyCompany\MyApp\Workspace

The values for MyCompany and MyApp are usually set in InitInstance. Always calling RestoreOriginalState() would break the code to allow user modifications to the toolbar.

Comment: +1 for explaining the state in registry. Question is should framework automatically clean the registry entry when cleaning/rebuilding whole solution? Obviously, we don't manually add entry to registry.

Comment: I delete the Registry state in the installer whenever the user installs a new version of the software. Ok, it has the disadvantage that the user loses the customizations to the UI but I think it is not that much of a problem.

Comment: The MFC Feature pack (BCG) has also a functionality to "integrate" the new UI elements into an existing state but I prefer to always start with a clean state. You might take a look here [CWinAppEx::CWinAppEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982381(v=VS.90).aspx) as a starting point for the resource smart update thing.

(second comment because I was only allowed to edit the comment within 5 minutes...)